# Karate framework and TestNG

Tags: testng, karate

Does Karate framework support for TestNG?
Does Karate framework generate any json file for TestNG as it does with JUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate used to support TestNG but has deprecated it. This should not be an issue because a) Karate does not need any TestNG features, b) You can Mix JUnit (which Karate supports) into your existing TestNG project without any problems.

Please read this for more details:  https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v0.9.0

And also refer these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050316/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69975722/143475