# How to run karate test runner file with TestNG?

Tags: karate

We have implemented cucumber with rest assured for API automation. Recently we came to know Karate giving advantages when compared with Rest assured. So I thought of recommend to my organization to use Karate, hence I have prepared sample to API automation scripts with Karate. Yes, I can execute very well with JUnit, but same testrunner file if I tried to execute with TestNG am unable to execute at all, displaying Test runs are zero after my execution.

Could you please help me is there any way to run Karate runner file with TestNG framwework. Really your answer going to make us decision.

I have gone through various posts which are related TestNG with Karate. But unluckily am unable to trigger my scripts.

Note: I have extended KarateRunner class and used @KarateOptions as well in my code.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is needed only for development mode. All teams finally need to do CI and here Karate does not need even JUnit, please refer this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution

Now for development mode - even if you insist on using TestNG, you can mix JUnit into the same project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19928639/143475

Please give up trying to use TestNG for Karate, it is un-necessary and a waste of your time. Also note that we have [IDE support](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/IDE-Support) which is what most developers will use. Even the JUnit support is not needed most of the time.