# can we run karate feature file from TestNG test Suit

Tags: karate

We are trying to introduce automation in our BU. There is a mixed uses case, where some test cases should be executed locally and some are UI and API testing. We have successfully automated the API and UI scenarios using karate framework, but the test cases which is executed locally are testNG maven project. We want to integrate it into one so that a full flow can be triggered.
can this be done?

After doing few research I found it can be done by parallel execution when I run it is giving me following error

failed features:
com.novell.CG.automation.test.API.API: API.feature:13 - failed to construct class by name: karate-http.properties not found, aborting
API.feature:19 - failed to construct class by name: karate-http.properties not found, aborting
API.feature:25 - failed to construct class by name: karate-http.properties not found, aborting
API.feature:31 - failed to construct class by name: karate-http.properties not found, aborting
com.novell.CG.automation.test.API.UI

```
public class MyRunner { 
 @Test void testAll() {
     Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 5);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not inlcuded the `karate-apache` maven dependency.

Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050316/143475

If still stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue