Karate + TestNG setup causes thread hanging issue
I am trying to implement Karate Labs framework within an already existing TestNG setup. But executing the test causes the thread to go WAITING stat indefinitely. Can someone identify the issue here
    @Test
    public void testRestCases() {
        try {
            String mName = "testRestCases";
            String path = staticPath + "apis.feature";
            LOG.info(CLASSNAME, mName, "Rest cases test started");
            Runner.path(path).parallel(1);
            LOG.info(CLASSNAME, mName, "Rest cases executed successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info(CLASSNAME, TLog.EXCEP_MSG, e);
        }
    }

I tried debugging the code to no avail. Here is the thread dump
"pool-20-thread-1@12631" tid=0x96 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:221)
      at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(CompletableFuture.java:1864)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:4011)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3959)
      at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(CompletableFuture.java:1898)
      at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:2117)
      at com.intuit.karate.Suite.run(Suite.java:247)
      at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.parallel(Runner.java:575)
      at com.zoho.transmail.testng.rest.RestAPITestUnit.testRestCases(RestAPITestUnit.java:29)
      at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/0x00001c0000194000.invokeVirtual(LambdaForm$DMH:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/0x00001c0000243400.invoke(LambdaForm$MH:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder.invokeExact_MT(Invokers$Holder:-1)
      at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invokeImpl(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:153)
      at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
      at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
      at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
      at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
      at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
      at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
      at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1583)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)



Please check this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589514/karate-framework-and-testng

actually there is a known problem with Karate versions <= 1.4.1 - refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78723452/143475
